# Remove item after a specified item from a linked list

Tags: java, linked-list

I have written a function that deletes the item that is next to the one being passed as a parameter. So far this function deletes but I feel like there is a better way to implement this.

```
public class MyLinked{
private class Node{
    Node next;
    double item;
    public Node(double item, Node next) {
        this.item = item;
        this.next = next;
    }
    public Node() {

    }
}
Node first;
```

Here is the function:

```
public void removeAfter(double x) {
    if(first == null) { return;}
    else {
        Node c = first;
        while(c!=null){
            if(c.item == x && c.next!=null) {
                c.next = c.next.next;
            }
            c = c.next;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> ```
>     if(first == null) { return;}
>     else {
>         Node c = first;
>         while(c!=null){
>             if(c.item == x && c.next!=null) {
>                 c.next = c.next.next;
>             }
>             c = c.next;
>         }
>     }
> ```

This could be written more briefly as

```
    for (Node c = first; c != null; c = c.next) {
        if (c.item == x && c.next != null) {
            c.next = c.next.next;
            return;
        }
    }
```

You don't need the first `if`, as the code has the same effect without it.

A `for` loop better captures the iterative properties here.

If we return immediately after doing our task, we save some iterations.

Another alternative would be

```
    if (first == null) {
        return;
    }

    for (Node current = first; current.next != null; current = current.next) {
        if (current.item == needle) {
            current.next = current.next.next;
            return;
        }
    }
```

I would prefer not to put everything on the same line.  This would be even more true if there was an `else`.

Since we `return`, we don't need an `else`.  This has the same effect without it, and we save the extra indentation.

I find `current` more descriptive than `c`.  Not a huge deal for a looping variable.

Since we know that `first` is not null, we can go ahead and check the `next`.  This saves us an iteration if we're looking for the last item.  This also saves having to check `next` later.

I find `needle` (meaning something for which we're searching) more descriptive than `x`.  That's a common idiom, but you can say `target`, etc. if that doesn't work for you.

You might consider returning the value that you remove.

```
            double value = current.next.item;
            current.next = current.next.next;
            return value;
```

This is common with `remove` operations.  You have the value right there at the time.  And this saves having to traverse the list twice to get the item and then remove it.  Of course, perhaps your usage patterns never have you doing that.

Comment: @J.user94 nicely put

Comment: By adding a `return` statement inside the `if` clause in the loop, you are altering the method's behavior, because the needle might appear more than once in the list. The original method of @J.user94 would delete *all* items in the list that are preceded by the needle, whereas yours only removes the first such item.

Answer (score 1):

> a better way to implement this

Your way looks fine. I'd say keep the code in the `while` loop.

The initial `if` is a bit odd, as it is redundant with the loop's logic. Just delete that initial test.

Perhaps that bitwise equality test on the double is exactly what you want, but many folks will choose to write `x == y` as `Math.abs(x - y) < epsilon`. You might prefer to have `removeAfter` accept a `Node` parameter, and to push the while loop into a separate `findNode` method.